# Pandas and for-loops: vectorizing operations and speeding up a python code

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, time-complexity, vectorization

**Motivation:**

I very often face a task where I need to check that dataframe's values are correct or not. Based on it I can create another dataframe with *True*/*False* values which are based on the first dataframe. I demonstrate an example of such a task below. I have a dataframe with logs, and I need to check that each value corresponds to a certain range. If it is in the range then an algorithm returns *True* in the corresponding cell of a new dataframe. Essentially the algorithm could be used to anomaly detection in dataframes. In simple examples, it is pretty easy to use *apply methods* and built in *NumPy* functions. Bellow is a nontrivial example for which I am struggling to find fast implementation.

**Input:**

I am trying to understand how to make code works faster by converting for-loops to vectorized operations.

**Desired output:**

Based on this dataframe I want to create a new dataframe where each value is **True** or **False** based on some specific rules

**Data:**

Data is presented in json format **data.json**:

```
[
 {
   "Med": "9/20/2020 8:50",
   "KE": 1,
   "SL": 154
 },
 {
   "Med": "9/20/2020 8:50",
   "KE": 2,
   "SL": 123
 },
 {
   "Med": "9/20/2020 8:50",
   "KE": 3,
   "SL": 132
 },
 {
   "Med": "9/20/2020 8:57",
   "KE": 1,
   "SL": 141
 },
 {
   "Med": "9/20/2020 8:57",
   "KE": 8,
   "SL": 151
 },
 {
   "Med": "9/20/2020 8:57",
   "KE": 2,
   "SL": 155
 },
 {
   "Med": "9/20/2020 9:12",
   "KE": 1,
   "SL": 151
 },
 {
   "Med": "9/20/2020 9:12",
   "KE": 5,
   "SL": 154
 },
 {
   "Med": "9/20/2020 9:12",
   "KE": 3,
   "SL": 144
 },
 {
   "Med": "9/20/2020 9:20",
   "KE": 1,
   "SL": 134
 },
 {
   "Med": "9/20/2020 9:20",
   "KE": 4,
   "SL": 155
 },
 {
   "Med": "9/20/2020 9:20",
   "KE": 3,
   "SL": 153
 }
]
```

**My implementation:**

I upload data as the following:

```
def upload_data(file):
    df = pd.read_json(file)
    df['Med'] = pd.to_Medtime(df['Med'], format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S") 
    df['EQE'] = np.nan
    return df
df = upload_data('data.json')
```

Next, I create an additional row. I managed to do it in a vectorized way:

```
df['EQE'] = (df['Med'] != df['Med'].shift()).cumsum()
```

Finally I create dataframe with the results:

```
def create_df_with_reslts(df):
    df_results = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df)
    df_results['Pred'] = np.nan
    return df_results
df_results = create_df_with_reslts(df)
```

And now I am looking at how to speed up and vectorize a main part of the code

```
def check_df(df, df_results):

    # check Med format
    Med_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        Med_string = row['Med']
        try:
            df_results['Med'][index] = True
        except ValueError:
            df_results['Med'][index] = False    

    # checking that number of KEs is between 1 and 500
    df_results['KE'] = np.where((df['KE'] >=1) & (df['KE'] <=500), True, False)
    
    # finding bordes for EQE's spans
    previous_row = df['Med'].astype(str)[0]
    EQE_index = 0
    EQE_list = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        # for same EQE
        if row['Med'] == previous_row:
            EQE_index += 1
            previous_row = row['Med']
        # for next EQE in table
        else:
            EQE_list.append(EQE_index)
            EQE_index = 1
            previous_row = row['Med']
    EQE_list.append(EQE_index)
    
    # checking whether or not borders are correct
    k=0
    for i in range(len(EQE_list)):
        if EQE_list[i] == 6 or EQE_list[i] == 8:
            for j in range(EQE_list[i]):
                df_results['EQE'][j+k] = True     
        else:
            for j in range(EQE_list[i]):
                df_results['EQE'][j+k] = False   
        j=EQE_list[i]
        k=k+j
    
    # Values of SL corresponds to uniform distribution with epsilon 10%
    list_of_columns = ['SL']   
    for n in range(len(list_of_columns)):
        # find the highest number for each EQE (EQE_MAX)
        k=0
        max_list = []  
        for i in range(len(EQE_list)):
            X = df[list_of_columns[n]][k:k+EQE_list[i]+1]
            max_list.append(X[X == X.max()].iloc[0])
            k=k+EQE_list[i]
        # check that each value in [max_list*10/100, max_list]
        k=0
        for i in range(len(EQE_list)):
            for j in range(EQE_list[i]):
                if float(df[list_of_columns[n]][j+k]) >= float(max_list[i])*90/100 and float(df[list_of_columns[n]][j+k]) <= float(max_list[i]):
                    df_results[list_of_columns[n]][j+k] = True
                else:
                    df_results[list_of_columns[n]][j+k] = False
            j=EQE_list[i]
            k=k+j
            
    # final results for each column
    df_results['Pred'] = df_results.prod(axis=1).astype(bool)
        
    # return max_list    
    return df_results
%timeit check_df(df, df_results)
# 19.5 ms ± 2.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I changed iteration over dataframe into iteration over iterrows: *range(len(df))* into *df.iterrows()*. It gave only ~20% speedup. Also one for-loop was changed with vectorized operation (*np.where*). I don't know how to do the same for other for-loops.

**My question:**

Is it possible to speedup and vectorize other parts of the code?

Comment: This is pretty extensive for a StackOverflow question. I would focus on one subsection that you are trying to vectorize and ask questions about how to do that. I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DavidErickson While this may be on-topic on CR, in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *Needs more focus* (as I'm doing here), *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Answer (score 1):

There's extensive number of posts you can read about using `.apply()` or numpy `where()` to speed up your code. When you consider `iterrows()`, look to other methods. I just took one of your iterrows functions and wrapped into a function for easy timing (using ipython) against other methods.

data is just your json you posted above.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data) # 12 rows based on your data
df_results =  pd.DataFrame() # create blank dataframe

def test_iter(): #your code inside a function 
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['UE'] >= 1 and row['UE'] <= 500:
            df_results['UE'][index] = True        
        else:
            df_results['UE'][index] = False 
%timeit test_iter()
1.42 ms ± 35.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df_results['UE'] = df.apply(lambda x: True if (x['UE'] >=1) & (x['UE'] <=500) else False, axis=1)
538 µs ± 20.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df_results['UE'] = np.where((df['UE'] >=1) & (df['UE'] <=500), True, False)
295 µs ± 12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

You can recode your other iterations to similar functionality. As the commenters have said, if you run into a specific issue after recoding, write up that question in a very concise manner providing details as you have in this post.